# Can the potential $V$ in the TDSE depend on the wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

I'm working on some derivations for a homework problem and need to verify whether $V$ is an operator dependent on the wavefunction or if $V$ is just some function.

If I have the following [(r,t)* V(r,t) - (r,t)V*(r,t)]. Does this equal 0 for all $V$? For instance, can $V$ include a derivative operator?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Pitaevskii_equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. In the [non-linear Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}= -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\Psi+\kappa \vert \Psi\vert^2 \Psi
$$
one can think of the term $\kappa \vert \Psi\vert^2$ as a potential that depends on probability density and thus on the modulus squared of the wavefunction itself.

In your specific example, if you work in momentum space, so that $\psi=\psi(p)$, then $x\psi(p)\mapsto i\hbar \partial_x\psi(p)$ so the potential $V\mapsto V(i\hbar \partial_x)$.  This can be useful in solving the linear potential with Hamiltonian
$$
\hat H=\frac{\hat p^2}{2m} - F \hat x ,
$$
which yields, in the momentum representation:
$$
i\hbar{\partial_t}\Psi(p,t)= \frac{p^2}{2m}\Psi(p,t)
-i\hbar F\partial_p\Psi(p,t)
$$
so the potential $-F\hat x$ depends on derivatives (w/r to $p$).
This is discussed for instance in

> Robinett, R. W. "Quantum mechanical time‐development operator for the uniformly accelerated particle." American Journal of Physics 64.6 (1996): 803-808.

Comment: That's cool, I hadn't heard of the non-linear TDSE. But for the original linear schrodinger equation, is it true that V will not depend on the wavefunction?

Comment: what's wrong with thinking of $V=\kappa \vert \Psi\vert^2$ as a potential term?  Else if you are claiming that $V$ cannot depend on $\Psi$ then you are answering your own question.